# What should I do if I am under a lot of pressure because our team-lead scolds me?

Tags: communication

Don't think I'm too impressionable, but I'm getting more and more pressured when our team lead goes through my mistakes all over the office and never says that I do most of the work right and I try never to repeat mistakes. It is very hard for me that everyone in our company overhears this, but I can not influence it in any way.

I am not a person who will be lazy and lazy, and I try to correctly combine the end of my university studies and work and gain experience, but at work I am literally afraid to even get up and go for coffee, because I am afraid to attract the attention of everyone, knowing what they think of me.

Comment: Can you expand a little more on what's going on?  How is his feedback on your mistakes being broadcast "all over the office", is it in standups or large meetings of some sort?  Is this how everyone else gets feedback as well or is it just you?  Have you talked to any colleagues or your team lead about this to see why, how they cope, say "I would rather get critique in private please,"...?

Comment: mxyzplk,it's a small company and we all work in the same office, he just needs to speak out loud.It is impossible to say something in person without leaving the office

Comment: Unfortunately, engineers and programmers can have abrasive personalities, especially when we're younger. There may not be much you can do about the personality, but it will improve in time as the people involved mature. If you want, you can tell  the team lead to please deliver feedback in private, and make a clear hint that they are acting in a way that is offensive. Might do them some good, although may make it more uncomfortable for you. Also depends on how long you are going to stay there.

Comment: Is the team lead singling you out in particular? Or does everyone on the team get some?

Comment: If your team lead is a bully, consider trying to find a new employer.

Comment: One thing to remember: you do **not** know what everyone thinks of you.  If people are busy they are more likely focused on their own work rather than someone who is entry-level.  Or they may be thinking "wow, the boss is a jerk".  Don't assume anything.

Comment: "Literally afraid of getting up to get coffee" this sounds extreme. What about lunch , bathroom etc? Assuming not "everyone" is responsible for your evaluation, why are you concerned about their opinions of you?

Answer (score 6):

I have similar people working with me. Know that whatever you'll do, they'll find a way to criticize your work. So don't put too much pressure on yourself.

Learn as much as you can and do what you can, then stop worrying about it. Accept the fact that you're going to get "scolded" anyway, and that nobody respects people who bellitle others for simple mistakes.

You have the right to make mistakes and your team lead makes mistakes too. Don't be ashamed of yourself. Just work normally and get used to him being a d*** until you find a better job. Know that nobody will think bad of you because of a little mistake, they will however, think bad of your team leader because he puts you on display like that. So go get your coffee with pride and don't care about what people think of you when you're doing the right thing.

A final little note, you may be experiencing social anxiety (not wanting to get coffee because you're afraid of what people think of you sounds a lot like me). So maybe you should see a therapist if this becomes persistent or if the symptoms worsen.